# Varieties of trees with logarithmic degree function

Tags: co.combinatorics, analytic-number-theory, enumerative-combinatorics, trees

I am interested in varieties of trees with a logarithmic degree function. I am currently looking at Bergeron, Flajolet, and Salvy's work "Varieties of increasing trees." They discuss exactly solvable models of increasing trees. In their notation the exponential generation function of a variety of trees satisfies

$$ Y'(z) = \phi(Y(z))\,, \quad Y(0) = 0 \,.$$

One can write down (I think) an interesting logarithmic degree function $\phi(w) = -\log(1-w)+1$ which describes a variety of non-planar trees with $s_r = (r-1)!$ nodes of degree $r$. I should preface my question by stating that I am extremely far from an expert in this field so I very much welcome any pointers to the literature. With this degree function we find the following for the exponential generating function:

$$ Y(z) = 1 - e^{1+Ei^{-1}(z/e + Ei(-1))} \,,$$

with $Ei(z) = \int_{-\infty}^z dt\frac{e^t}{t}$ and $Ei^{-1}(z)$ the inverse exponential integral function which is holomorphic away from $z=0$. I believe the asymptotics of the EGF go like $\sim \rho^{-n} n^{-2}$ where the nearest singularity is $\rho = e-Ei(-1)$. I am wondering if this soluble model appears in the analytic combinatorics literature. I am a little confused that the coefficients of $Y(z)$ appear to count increasing labelled rooted trees which naively have a different degree function.